# Getting Next Router was not mounted error when trying to access the locale variable in the path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to access the locale and locales properties from use router. I am importing this from next/router. This issue is happening when I am importing from `next/router`.

When I change the import to `next/navigation` the issue is gone. But I'm not able to access the locale and locales.

Comment: Hi Subin, have you checked the below answer? Let us know please.

Answer (score 0):

Within the [app](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, and as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#routing-overview), Next.js passes your locales to every page and layout as props:

> ensure all special files inside `app/` are nested under `app/[lang]`. This enables the Next.js router to dynamically handle different locales in the route, and forward the `lang` parameter to every layout and page. For example:

```
// app/[lang]/page.js

// You now have access to the current locale
// e.g. /en-US/products -> `lang` is "en-US"
export default async function Page({ params: { lang } }) {
  return ...
}
```